# Scala fasterxml jackson. Reading in a Yaml file, but the return data structure is difficult to work with

Tags: scala, parsing, jackson, yaml, fasterxml

I am Writing a scala method that reads in a Yaml file and returns a Map of the content of the Yaml file.  I can do this successfully, but working with the data structure is very cumbersome as I will demonstrate below.

Note I can and have used jackson in scala to take a yaml file and constitute it into a case class.  That works great and is not cumbersome to use.  In this problem the yaml is dynamic so we need to put it into a dynamic data structure i.e  Map or List of Map

In Java there is no issue in solving the problem.  The data structure that is returned back is easy to work with.

Java example:

```
    public Map readMapYml(String fullFileName) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(new File(fullFileName), Map.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("JavaParser->writeYml: 
           Unable to write yaml file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My equivalent scala code. (I have also tried many variation of the code below)

```
def readMapYml(fullFileName: String): Map[String,Any] = {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  try {
    mapper.readValue(new File(fullFileName), classOf[Map[String,Any]])
  }
  catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      throw new RuntimeException("Parser->readMapYml: Unable to read yaml 
    file to map.  filename: " + fullFileName + " Message: " + e.getMessage)
   }
 }
```

So this works and I can parse through the data, but it is really cumbersome.

Example of how cumbersome:

```
   result.get("groups").get.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String,Any]]](0).get("group").get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]].get("colors").get.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String,Any]]](0).get("color").get
```

Btw interop works just fine I can write this in Java and call it from scala.  However, in this case we need to get our scala code working

My question: I would like fasterxml Jackson to return a data structure that is much easier to use similar to the data structure I get back when done through Java.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One of the difficulties with the following approach is that it requires the datatype to be defined every time we extract the data it takes up datatype Any - thereby forcing us to define the data type for values.

```
mapper.readValue(new File(fullFileName), classOf[Map[String,Any]])
```

Since the YAML file is expected to be dynamic, it is better to use the much more developed JsonNode data type from Jackson, leveraging following approach:

```
  val yaml = mapper.readValue(new File(fullFileName), classOf[Any])
  val jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(yaml)
  val jsonObj = mapper.readTree(jsonString)
```

The resulting jsonObj is of [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) data type, which will have a dynamic schema & supports data conversion/typecasting needs with its in-built methods

Comment: The underline question is how to make the Scala implementation as easy to work with as the Java implementation.  Unfortunately, Interoperability is off the table not because it would not work but because they did not want it.  In Java this is easy.  When I wrote the question I was not looking at how to do it.  I was looking for an easier less complicated solution then the one I was using to solve the problem.  Note I no longer work with Scala so it is not a problem, but I would think other using faster xml would want a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does a good job navigating a kv map returned from Jackson.

```
  /**
* Purpose is to parse through a generic kv map of data returned from Jackson.
* @param structure data return from Jackson or a sub-structure of data returned from 
  Jackson
* @param path  A path to the data we want to return.  A stack so order is leaf to 
  branch to branch .... to root
* @return the section requested.  The first item added to your stack.  In other words 
  the last item pop.
*/
```

def getStructure(structure: Any, path: mutable.Stack[String]): Any  = {

```
var retVal: Any = structure

if (path.nonEmpty) {
  structure match {
    case map: Map[String, Any] =>
      retVal = map.get(path.pop())
    case some: Some[Any] =>
      retVal = some.get
    case list: List[Any] =>
      retVal = list(path.pop().toInt)
    case None =>
      throw new IllegalStateException("DataHelper->getStructure: Bad path keyword does not exist in section of path.  remaining stack: " + path)
    case _ =>
      throw new IllegalStateException("DataHelper->getStructure: Structure type is unexpected.  Type: " + structure.getClass.getName)
  }
  if (path.nonEmpty) {
    retVal = getStructure(retVal, path)
  }
}

retVal match {
  case some: Some[Any] =>
    retVal = some.get //If the last item is a some get the content of the some.
  case _ =>
}

retVal
```

}

Test code:

```
test("testMyDataHelper") {
val mapParser = new MapParser
val result = mapParser.readMapYml("test.yaml")
var path = mutable.Stack[String]()

path.push("name","0","groups")
println(DataHelper.getStructure(result, path))//Joe
path.push("name","1","groups")
println(DataHelper.getStructure(result, path))//Bill
path.push("part2","0","items","0","groups")
println(DataHelper.getStructure(result,path))//dash
path.push("part2","2","items","0","groups")
println(DataHelper.getStructure(result,path))//line
//Example of getting a subsection of yaml
path.push("items","0","groups")
val subsection = DataHelper.getStructure(result,path)
//use the subsection
path.push("part1","2")
println(DataHelper.getStructure(subsection,path))//green
path.push("part2","0")
println(DataHelper.getStructure(subsection,path))//dash
```

}

yaml file

```
document: "0.0.1"
groups:
- version: "0.0.0"
  type: "A"
  name: "Joe"
  agency: "skjenco"
  number: 8
  items:
  - part1: "red"
    part2: "dash"
  - part1: "brown"
    part2: "underline"
  - part1: "green"
    part2: "line"
- version: "0.0.1"
  type: "B"
  name: "Bill"
  agency: "billco"
  number: 3
  items:
  - part1: "orange"
    part2: "line"
  - part1: "pink"
    part2: "dash"
  - part1: "blue"
    part2: "line"
```